# Domino 9 Designer Debugger won't show source from Custom Control

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

When trying to debug a Xpage the debugger will not display the source code for a Custom Control when debugging. The debugger still stops at a breakpoint set on a code line in the Custom Control and I can step through but the source is always the parent Xpage.

The visual symptoms are that the debugger stops at the breakpoint but the visual line is from the parent Xpage and not from the actual line in the Custom Control.
When debugging a Xpage everything is fine…

Are there any settings I have set/not set?

Please advice!